# Traversing object hierarchy based on provided keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, data-structures, data-modeling

I have a function that accepts the following arguments:

```
set(section, field, pair, component, element, value)
```

The ***section***, ***field***, ***pair*** and ***component*** are just keys within the Object. They are way-points so we can travel down the hierarchy. Obviously ***section*** is the head, our entry point.

***element*** is the target key and the ***value*** is the value that will be set.

Since, there are elements at different depths, I would like to do the following:

```
set('utility', null, null, null, 'exportId', 'banana')
```

This is for a shallow access, and internally it will do this:

```
dataObj[section][element] = value;

**/ As in
 * data: {
      utility: {
         exportId: 'banana'
      }
 *  }
 */
```

In other cases, when the element is deeper inside the Object, it may be required to do the following:

```
dataObj[section][field][pair][component][element] = value;
```

What would be the best way, to define the path to the element dynamically, so we skip the keys that are passed in as a 'null'?

for example:

```
set('history', 'current', null, null, 'fruit', 'apple')

**/ As in
 * data: {
      history: {
         current: {
           fruit: 'apple'
        }
      }
 *  }
 */
```

will internally be constructed as:

```
dataObj[section][field][element] = value;
```

as you might have noticed, we skipped `[pair][component]` because those slots were passed in as `null`(s).

Comment: You would be better off with an array and not defined arguments. Simple loop over the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to get the arguments passed to an array. Then create an object using [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceright)

```js
function set(...paths) { 
  return paths.reduceRight((r, key, i) => key !== null ? { [key] : r } : r)  
}

console.log(set('history', 'current', null, null, 'fruit', 'apple'))
console.log(set('utility', null, null, null, 'exportId', 'banana'))
```

---

The above function will **construct** a nested object based on the paths. If you want to just update an existing object, you could traverse the object and set the value like this:

```js
function set(dataObj, ...paths) {
  let value = paths.pop(),
      nested = dataObj;

  for (let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    const path = paths[i];

    if (i === paths.length - 1 && nested)
      nested[path] = value; // set the value if it's the final item

    if (path !== null && nested)
      nested = nested[path]; // get another level of nesting
  }

  return dataObj;
}

let obj = { utility: { exportId: 'banana' } }

console.log(set(obj, 'utility', null, null, null, 'exportId', 'orange'))

obj = {
  history: {
    current: {
      fruit: 'apple'
    }
  }
}

console.log(set(obj, 'history', 'current', null, null, 'fruit', 'orange'))
```

Comment: And I use that object as a means to traverse my original data structure?

Comment: @mbilyanov sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: Because, those keywords are a bit like a map, in a sense the way-points to be followed in order to reach the key that needs to be changed, I was not sure how would I be using the result of the `reduce` to traverse my original data set. So I guess, I will use it to move down the hierarchy per each key in the result of the `reduce` for each key in my original data-structure.

Comment: @mbilyanov I have updated the code. Not sure if this is what you need though.

Comment: Your solution is a good answer to the question. Thanks! One issue though, all the arguments, apart from last two `exportId` and `orange` are all nested. I'm trying to fix your code so that we actually walk down the hierarchy, So `history', 'current', null, null, 'fruit', 'apple'` would be `history: { current: { fruit: apple } }`

Comment: I think that was the main issue, concatenating the paths, so the first path is `[history]` then on the next cycle of the loop, the path becomes `[history][current]` then we skip next tow cycles as they are `nulls`, and then we stop to set the value with `[history][current][fruit]=apple`.

Comment: @mbilyanov the second approach works only if the path *exists*. Obviously, `set('history', 'current', null, null, 'fruit', 'apple')` wouldn't work with this object which has `utility` and `exportId` as paths. I assumed, that would be called another object like `{
      history: {
         current: {
           fruit: 'apple'
        }
      }
  }`which has all these nested properties in that order.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a long list of specific parameters, just pass an object to the function. this way you only pass what you need to and there won't be any "null" references to deal with on the call.

Using this implementation, this call can be shortened to something like this:

Your current implementation:

```
 set('utility', 'current', null, null, 'exportId', 'banana')
```

Using an object as the parameter:

```
set({
   section:'utility', 
   field:'current', 
   element: 'exportId', 
   value:'banana'
});
```

Comment: Let me test it. I think I had it setup like that before. Not exactly the answer to my question, as it will require changing the implementation, but it might work as a solution. I would be happy to accept it and move on, as it might render my whole question a bit pointless.